# Can you insert a static tag into a style tag?

Tags: html, css, django

I'm trying to link the proper path for a static file but I can't seem to insert that static tag into a style tag.

```
{% load static %} 
<header class="masthead"  style="{% static 'background-image:url('/blog/img/home.jpg')'%}">
```

The errror message I get it:

Could not parse the remainder: '/blog/img/home.jpg')'' from ''background-image:url('/blog/img/home.jpg')''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is `blog/img/home.jpg` so this needs to be in the static brackets

```
<header class="masthead"  style="background-image:url({% static '/blog/img/home.jpg' %})">
```